# Why ist the Value of my Array of Object still the same in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm confused why my array of Object still at the same. I was trying to count the index from the Array. How I can count the index?

```
public class TryArray {

    Students[] arr;

    public void add(Students std) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            arr[i] = std;
         System.out.println(std); //it willbe more than one time displayed
            break;
        }
    }

    public TryArray(int lengthOfArray) { //Constructor for the length Array
        arr = new Students[lengthOfArray];
    }
}
```

And here is my main class `test1.java`

```
public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryArray val = new TryArray(4);
        Students a1 = new Students(1, "Bob", "Julius");
        Students a2 = new Students(2, "Joe", "Chris");
        Students a3 = new Students(3, "Christian", "Henderson");
        Students [] arr = {a1,a2,a3};       
        val.add(a1);
        val.add(a2);
        val.add(a3);
    }
}
```

**Expected output :**

```
1, Bob, Julius
2, Joe, Chris
3, Christian, Henderson
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Let's see a couple of things: 1) fields in `Students` class must not be `static`. 2) We need to see code of `TryArray#add`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "count the index" means exactly, but in the `for` loop, you have a `break;` right after you print the first element in the `add`. Consequently, you'll only ever see the `[0]` element.

Comment: in `Students` class it's just `constructors` nothing else. that was the code of `TryArray#add` @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: but if i dont write `break;` and I want to display my **the Objects of Array  ** it will be display twice. I want display  **one time** @KevinO

Comment: If I put in inside `for` loop like this : `arr[i] = std` and without `break;` and display it using `System.out.println`, it will be **more than one time displayed**

Comment: Then move it out of the loop.  Having the `break` there is, in fact, breaking your code.

Comment: it will be **9 time** displayed if i remove the `break;`

Comment: You will have to solve that problem some other way than having the `break;` there, because your program will not be correct as long as it is there.

Comment: and how then @LouisWasserman ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of misconceptions in your current code. First, you're setting **all the elements** of the array with the element you want to add. Second, in `add` method you're printing the variable **times the length of the array** without thinking on the proper result.

Code of your `TryArray` class may be rewritten like this:

```
public class TryArray {

    //array to store the students (elements)
    private Students[] arr;
    //counter of how many students are stored by this instance
    private int size;

    public void add(Students std) {
        /*
        the code here makes no sense, see explanation above
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            arr[i] = std;
         System.out.println(std); //it willbe more than one time displayed
            break;
        }
        */
        if (size < arr.length) {
            arr[size++] = std;
            //this is for testing purposes only, in real life code
            //you shall avoid code like this here
            System.out.println(std);
        }
    }

    public TryArray(int lengthOfArray) { //Constructor for the length Array
        arr = new Students[lengthOfArray];
    }
}
```